# Power law distribution

Tags: r, power-law

My data set is very simple, just one variable "Step.length.in.mm", right now I try to use power law distribution package to get my Xmin and pars, my code is:

```
# install.packages("poweRlaw")  
library("poweRlaw")  

m=file$Step.length.in.mm

est=estimate_xmin(m)

m$setXmin(est)
```

The error message

> Error: $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors

Can anyone tell me how to solve this?

Comment: `$` is short for `[[` and you don't `x[[1]]` a vector, you `x[1]`a vector

Comment: so what should I do here?

Comment: m=file[Step.length]   ??

Comment: Look at the associated [vignettes](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/poweRlaw/) for the package. In particular, read the Introduction to the poweRlaw package. Currently your question doesn't make sense, i.e. what is `file`?

Comment: "file" is my data name

Comment: "step.length.in.mm" is my variable name